# Unexpected token 'this' while creating method inside object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this

I am creating an object and I continue to get the error message *unexpected token:this* when I add a method. Here's my code.

```
function Person(name,age,gender,job) {
    this.name = name,
    this.age = age,
    this.gender = gender,
    this.job = job,
    this.pSpeak = function() { 
        func.innerHTML = "My name is " + this.name + "<br>I am " this.age + "years old." + "<br>I am a " + this.gender + ".<br>My career is " + this.job +".";
        } //Object Method
    }

 var colin = new Person("Colin James",24,"man","Social Media Consultant"); // create a new Person.
```

I have read various articles about creating methods within objects and I don't see where I am going wrong here. When I remove the `this.` syntax from the *name, age, gender, job* variables in the method pSpeak, I get the error *Unexpected identifyer*.

Any suggestions as to whats happening?

Comment: you missed `+` in string `"<br>I am " this.age` should be `"<br>I am " + this.age`

Comment: @monkeyinsight Thank you! That was it. I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Honestly I did read it over and over, however I kept missing it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a `+` when setting the `innerHTML`.

```
function Person(name,age,gender,job) {
    this.name = name,
    this.age = age,
    this.gender = gender,
    this.job = job,
    this.pSpeak = function() { 
        func.innerHTML = "My name is " + this.name + "<br>I am " + this.age + "years old." + "<br>I am a " + this.gender + ".<br>My career is " + this.job +".";
        } //Object Method
    }

 var colin = new Person("Colin James",24,"man","Social Media Consultant"); // create a new Person.
```